# Cancan showing all transactions instead of only authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using cancan and I have this in the UserTransactionsController

```
class UserTransactionsController < ApplicationController

load_and_authorize_resource

def index
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id]
  @user_transactions = @company.user_transactions.order("date DESC").all
...
```

And in ability.rb I have:

```
can [:read], UserTransaction do |ut|
  ut.company_user.user.id == user.id
end
```

The line ut.company_user.user.id == user.id never seems to get hit.  And it is always showing all user transactions, also those for other users.

Comment: in `UserTransaction` you find `company_user` then `user` then `id`? its no have `user_id`? so you just need `ut.user_id = user.id`

Comment: This doesn't make a difference either.  The strange thing is in debug the compare line does not get hit, the line above does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rept, when you use the load_and_authorize_resource method, you don't need to create @user_transactions variable, that's what the method does based on the ability.rb file.

you are rewriting the @user_transactions that load_and_authorize_resource creates with the line:

```
@user_transactions = @company.user_transactions.order("date DESC").all
```

if you need to fetch users transactions that belong to that particular company you are fetching, you can use the accessible_by scope that cancan provides as:

```
@user_transactions = @company.user_transactions.accessible_by(current_ability).order("date DESC").all
```

this should help if you haven't figured it out by now, you can read more on cancan documentation on this topic here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

Comment: This indeed is the solution.  Only problem I'm having after declaring your line is I get:
CanCan::Error: The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition.
I looked this up and got several hits, (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/710) I however can't find how to rewrite the can definition in Ability.rb to accept this.

Comment: @rept `can :read, UserTransaction, company_user_id: user.company_user_ids` asuming UserTransaction belongs_to company_user and that User has_many :company_users, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like...

```
can :manage, UserTransaction
```

or

```
can :manage, :all
```

before

```
can [:read], UserTransaction {|ut| ut.company_user.user.id == user.id}
```

you will be able to read all transactions because "manage" is strongest than "read"

Comment: There is no other UserTransaction in the cancan ability.rb